# How to give a point when answer is correct with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a (small) problem, I tried looking on the internet, but can't find the answer. I'm new with javascript.

HTML:

```
    <form name="examen">
     <input type="radio" id="1a" name="1" value="">Answer 1<br></input>
     <input type="radio" id="1b" name="1" value="">Answer 2<br></input>
     <input type="radio" id="1c" name="1" value="">Answer 3<br></input>
     <input type="radio" id="1d" name="1" value="">Answer 4<br></input>
     <input type="button" name="knop" value="Bereken" onClick="calculatie()">
    </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 function calculatie() {
  var calc = "Aantal vragen goed: ";
  var totaal = parseInt(0);
     if(document.examen.1c.checked){totaal += parseInt(1);} 
  calc += Math.round(totaal);
   alert(calc);
  }
```

Now, when a user is clicking on answer 3, the total points need to be one. But it is saying NaN, I can't get it right. The code needs to be in JAVASCRIPT/HTML. I can't use PHP.

Comment: You can't use symbols names starting with a number. `1c` is not a valid neither as an `id` attribute name nor as variable/symbol name in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your js code:

```
function calculatie() {

   var calc = "Aantal vragen goed: ";
   var totaal = 0;
   if(document.getElementById("1c").checked){totaal += 1;} 
   alert(totaal);
  };
```

document.getElementById("1c") returns true or false,weather "Answer 3" is checked or not and in case it is checked adds 1 to "totaal" variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this function ...

```
function calculatie() { 
  var calc = "Aantal vragen goed: ";
  var totaal = 0;
     if(document.getElementById('1c').checked == true){
         totaal += 1;} 
       calc += Math.round(totaal);
       console.log(calc); //see console log for output or use it as u want
  }
```

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/a5oegt6z/) is the fiddle